# Hiding implementation of Serialization

Tags: java, interface

In a university coding task week ago I had to make list of some users which will be kept in a Collection(e.g. ArrayList) which should be serialized on-demand, and that implementation of Serialization should be hiden behind specific interface. As far as I know, you are not allowed to implement any method in interface (let's pretend Java 8+ doesn't exist and there is no default keyword), so I dont have any idea besides using Abstract class to do this. Is there any classical Java solution for this task? How should I do the implementation of serialization then?

Comment: What Serialization implementation? Are you talking about `java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: Yes, simple writeObject, that's no burden, I have problem with the idea of hiding serialization method in interface

Comment: The serialization methods are `private` why to hide them in any other way?

Comment: You need to seek clarification. The Serialization implementation is already hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the `java.io.Serializable` interface is a classical way (but not exclusive).

Custom serialization for `Serializable` class relies on `private` methods defined in the serializable class :

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

So de facto, the serialization implementation would be hidden (as defined in  private methods) and the clients of the class would know only that the class is defined as implementing `Serializable`.